# How to get fees for forwarding donations from one PayPal user to another?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, donations

Basically the site will be offering users an easy way to donate to other users/companies who are looking to raise money. The people trying to raise money will get good stats about how much donations they are getting and so on.

For that my site would charge a small fee of like ~3%. How is that possible with PayPal? Should I be looking at Adaptive Payments API? Or is it something else.

Comment: If my answer solved your question would you mind marking it as solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

```
"Chained payments enable a sender to send a single payment to a primary receiver. 
The primary receiver keeps part of the payment and pays secondary 
receivers the remainder."
```

At the section on chained payments. It looks like you can set yourself as the primary receiver so long as you have a PayPal business account and receive x amount of money for the donation, then give the rest to one or more other secondary receivers.